# How can I make the React Components Dev tool readable / more useful?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to troubleshoot a component but find it nearly impossible to locate b.c. the React Dev tools explicitly put all this excess information into the component hierarchy.

Particularly `Connect Function` and `Context.Provider`.  The nesting level gets absurd.  Maybe even ludicrous.

As a side question what does `memo` stand for and mean?

It just easier to inspect the HTML directly with out the tools.  Could not find a tag for React dev tools.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In dev tools if you click on the gear to get to the settings then click on the `Components` tab in the settings there are filtering options to hide components in the tree based on a wide variety of conditions.

You can see a little animated screenshot of this here: https://reactjs.org/blog/2019/08/15/new-react-devtools.html#where-did-all-of-the-dom-elements-go